# Hive Error: ORC does not support type conversion from DATE to TIMESTAMP

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a source table in Hive with DDL as:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE JRNL.SOURCE_TAB(
  ticket_id varchar(11),
  ttr_start timestamp,
  ttr_stop timestamp
)
PARTITIONED BY (
  exp_dt string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\u0001'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://my.cluster.net:8020//db/data/SOURCE_TAB'
  TBLPROPERTIES (
  'last_modified_by'='edpintdatd',
  'last_modified_time'='1466093031',
  'serialization.null.format'='',
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1466093031')
```

When I am querying the table:

```
hive> select exp_dt from JRNL.SOURCE_TAB limit 3;
```

It is giving me an Exception:

```
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.io.IOException: ORC does not support type conversion from DATE to TIMESTAMP
```

Even when I tried to create a replica table like the above source, using:

```
CREATE TABLE JRNL.SOURCE_TAB_BKP(
  ticket_id varchar(11),
  ttr_start timestamp,
  ttr_stop timestamp
)
PARTITIONED BY (exp_dt string);
```

and then inserting data in this table using:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE JRNL.SOURCE_TAB_BKP PARTITION (exp_dt)
  SELECT
  ticket_id,
  ttr_start,
  ttr_stop,
  exp_dt string
FROM JRNL.SOURCE_TAB;
```

it is still giving me the error `ORC does not support type conversion from DATE to TIMESTAMP`
I tried using

```
to_utc_timestamp(unix_timestamp(ttr_start),'UTC'),
to_utc_timestamp(unix_timestamp(ttr_stop),'UTC'),
```

but this isn't helping either.
I have already set the `hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict`.
I even used `CAST(.... as DATE)`, `CAST(.... as TIMESTAMP)`. Didn't work either.

Comment: Apparently `ttr_start` and/or `ttr_end` are of `date` type and not `timestamp`. Define you external table accordingly.

Comment: But DDL of the source "JRNL.SOURCE_TAB" is `timestamp`. I tried changing the DDL of replica table "JRNL.SOURCE_TAB_BKP" from `timestamp` to `date`, but exception remains the same. I suspect the data might be corrupted.

Comment: `JRNL.SOURCE_TAB_BKP` DDL is not interesting since you already fail on reading `JRNL.SOURCE_TAB`. Change `JRNL.SOURCE_TAB` columns from `timestamp` to `date`

Comment: if i do that, what will happen to the data in this source table ?...because data is already present in the source

Comment: Even if you drop external table only the table definition is being deleted. The data is not being touched. Same for schema changes. `alter table JRNL.SOURCE_TAB replace columns (ticket_id varchar(11),ttr_start date,ttr_stop date) cascade;`